# Force title break in apa6e

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, apa6

*Apologies in advance: this is not minimal in the example but I am afraid my lack of knowledge about what packages control what could lead me to leave out packages that have an effect on the output.*

I want to break the title of a document where I desire, not where LaTeX or packages do. My title is currently broken like this:

```
Research Analysis Exam: A Critique of ``Evidence in Teacher Education: The Performance As-
sessment for California Teachers (PACT)''
```

I want to break it like this:

```
Research Analysis Exam: A Critique of ``Evidence in Teacher Education: 
The Performance Assessment for California Teachers (PACT)''
```

Though centered of course.  How can I do this but allow LaTeX to hyphenate the rest of the article in its usual way?

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{RAE}   %SUPPLY YOUR NAME OF BIBLATEX HERE (REMEMEBER NO SPACES IN THIS NAME)
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=normal,up]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{microtype}  %disable ligitures
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\thispagestyle{titlepage}%
\vspace*{1in}%
\Centering\@title\\\@author%
\vfill%
\ifdefined%
\apaSIXe@leavefloats{}
\fi
\RaggedRight%
\mspart{\@title}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{1 em}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
\@float{figure}
}{%
\@float{figure}[#1]%
}%
\centering
}{%
\end@float
}
\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
\@float{table}
}{%
\@float{table}[#1]%
}%
\centering
}{%
\end@float
}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
\section{\normalfont\refname}}

\title{Research Analysis Exam: A Critique of ``Evidence in Teacher Education: The Performance Assessment for California Teachers (PACT)''}
\shorttitle{Research Analysis Exam}
\author{Tyler Rinker}
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\section{Précis}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force a break by selecting an appropriate paragraph box width, like `13cm`:

```
\title{%
  \texorpdfstring
    {\parbox{13cm}{\centering Research Analysis Exam: A Critique of ``Evidence in Teacher Education: 
      The Performance Assessment for California Teachers (PACT)'' \par\kern\baselineskip}}
    {Research Analysis Exam}}
```

Also, since your current setup (using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) puts the contents of `\title` in the bookmarks, it may be advisable to use `\texorpdfstring` in order to separate TeX content from ASCII content (used in bookmarks).